# How to precalculate valid number of combinations instead of using while loop?

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, while-loop

Given List of datacenters which are dc1, dc2, dc3 and list of machines, h1, h2, h3, h4 as mentioned below -

```
Datacenters = dc1, dc2, dc3
Machines = h1, h2, h3, h4
```

I want to generate below combinations only -

```
a)  {dc1=h1, dc3=h3, dc2=h2}

b)  {dc1=h2, dc3=h4, dc2=h3}

c)  {dc1=h3, dc3=h1, dc2=h4}

d)  {dc1=h4, dc3=h2, dc2=h1}
```

Each datacenter in the each pass should get alternate machines/hosts. They should not get same machines. For example in `a` as shown above - `dc1 gets h1`, `dc2 gets h2`, `dc3 gets h3` so all the machines are different for each datacenters. And in the second pass as shown in `b` - now `dc1 gets h2` (becuase dc1 already got h1 in the first pass), `dc2 got h3` (bcoz dc2 already got h2 in the first pass), and `dc3 got h4`(bcoz dc3 already got h3 in the first pass) and etc etc.

And one more example -  if I have only three hosts, then below combination I am supposed to get only -

```
Datacenters = dc1, dc2, dc3
Machines = h1, h2, h3    

{dc1=h1, dc3=h3, dc2=h2}
{dc1=h2, dc3=h1, dc2=h3}
{dc1=h3, dc3=h2, dc2=h1}
```

So I came up with the below code which works perfectly fine -

```
public class DataCenterMapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(Arrays.asList("dc1", "dc2", "dc3"), Arrays.asList(
        "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"));

        // is there any way to avoid while loop here?
        while (true) {
            Map<String, String> coloHost = dcm.getDatacenterMachineMapping();
            System.out.println(coloHost);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : coloHost.entrySet()) {

            }
        }
    }
}

class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private boolean firstCall = true;
    private int hostListIndex = 0;
    private List<String> datacenterList, hostList;
    private Map<String, Set<String>> dataCenterHostsMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    public DatacenterMachineMapping(List<String> datacenterList, List<String> hostList) {
    this.datacenterList = datacenterList;
    this.hostList = hostList;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDatacenterMachineMapping() {
    Map<String, String> datacenterMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (!firstCall) {
        if (hostListIndex <= 0) {
        hostListIndex = hostList.size();
        }
        hostListIndex--;
    } else {
        firstCall = false;
    }
    for (String datacenter : datacenterList) {
        if (hostListIndex == hostList.size()) {
        hostListIndex = 0;
        }
        if (addDataCenterHost(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex))) {
        datacenterMachineMapping.put(datacenter, hostList.get(hostListIndex++));
        }
    }
    hostListIndex--;
    return datacenterMachineMapping;
    }

    private boolean addDataCenterHost(String datacenter, String host) {
    Set<String> dataCenterHostSet = dataCenterHostsMap.get(datacenter);
    if (dataCenterHostSet == null) {
        dataCenterHostSet = new HashSet<String>();
        dataCenterHostsMap.put(datacenter, dataCenterHostSet);
    }
    return dataCenterHostSet.add(host);
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

The only problem is I have a while loop which will keep on running always,

Is there any way I can precalculate the number of valid combinations instead of using while loop?

Comment: number of valid combinations = Max(Datacenters_Count, Machines_Count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking math.  The answer is (n choose k), where n is the number of machines, and k is the number of datacenters.

The reason is the following:  The ordering doesn't really matter, so we'll assume that the Datacenters are always arranged in the same order.  For the first data center, we can pick any one of the `n` machines.  For the second, we can pick any one of the machines, except for the one picked before, thus `n * (n-1)`.  The next data center will lead to `n * (n-1) * (n-2)` possible situations.

Thus, if you had 10 machines, and 4 datacenters, you would have:

`10 * 9 * 8 * 7` possibile combinations.

More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

If you want a function to do the work for you , it is in the Apache commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#binomialCoefficientDouble%28int,%20int%29

However, if you are actually wanting to *generate* those combinations, then you need a for loop.

Comment: Thanks. Which Maven dependency I am supposed to use for this from this [list](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons). Its little bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you've asked here, but i think i can see where the problem is, each time get call get mapping you only generate 1 row. so i've rewritten the code so it generates all of them and gives you back a list of the maps. so you can do what you need with them.

```
public class DataCenterMapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DatacenterMachineMapping dcm = new DatacenterMachineMapping(
                Arrays.asList("dc1", "dc2", "dc3"), Arrays.asList("h1", "h2",
                        "h3", "h4"));


            List<Map<String, String>> coloHost = dcm
                    .getDatacenterMachineMappings();

            System.out.println(coloHost);

    }
}

class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private boolean firstCall = true;
    private int hostListIndex = 0;
    private List<String> datacenterList, hostList;

    public DatacenterMachineMapping(List<String> datacenterList,
            List<String> hostList) {
        this.datacenterList = datacenterList;
        this.hostList = hostList;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getDatacenterMachineMappings() {
        List<Map<String, String>> grid = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < datacenterList.size(); i++) {

            Map<String, String> datacenterMachineMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String[] line = new String[hostList.size()];
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                int off = j + i;
                if (off >= datacenterList.size()) {
                    off -= datacenterList.size();
                }
                datacenterMachineMapping.put(hostList.get(j) ,datacenterList.get(off));
            }

            grid.add(datacenterMachineMapping);
        }
        return grid;
    }

}
```

example output:

```
[{h4=dc1, h1=dc1, h3=dc3, h2=dc2}, {h4=dc2, h1=dc2, h3=dc1, h2=dc3}, {h4=dc3, h1=dc3, h3=dc2, h2=dc1}]
```

Comment: I just ran the code, it gave `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`. I just added one more host in `hostsList` as `h5` and then ran it.

Comment: And also, if you see the output, it has dc1 twice, dc2 twice.. In one row, it should be either dc1, dc2, dc3 only..